# Faulty right alignment for comments in algorithmic package

Tags: horizontal-alignment, comments, pseudocode, algorithmic

I'm trying to right align comments in a pseudocode environment using the algorithmic package. So I renewed the `algorithmiccomment` command.

There's a different way to create comments for "normal" statements and for pre-defined statements such as "for", "if", etc.

The problem is, that the right alignment differs for the "normal" comments and the others. How can that be fixed, so that all comments nicely align?

Here's what I mean.

[image: Comments not really aligned well]

And this is the code to reproduce my example. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{\hfill \tiny//~#1\normalsize}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}
\FORALL[This comment is not quite right aligned]{ $a \in B$}
    \STATE X  \COMMENT{This comment is further to the right}
\ENDFOR
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Thanks. I accepted your answer. But your "starter guide" link is broken.

Comment: Wait. Now it works =)

Comment: Glad to help. The "welcome" message is a standard one we use over here :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't mind to switch to the `algorithmicx` package (`algpseudocode` variant) the issue is solved.

Note that I've loaded it with the `compatible` option so you can use your old algorithms without any change.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[compatible]{algpseudocode} % or \usepackage{algcompatible}
\renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{\bgroup\hfill\tiny//~#1\egroup}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}
\FORALL[This comment is not quite right aligned]{ $a \in B$}
    \STATE X  \COMMENT{This comment is further to the right}
\ENDFOR
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

And this is how it should be written in "proper" `algorithmicx` syntax:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{\bgroup\hfill\tiny//~#1\egroup}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}
\ForAll{ $a \in B$} \Comment{This comment is not quite right aligned}
    \State X \Comment{This comment is further to the right}
\EndFor
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```