# How to align comments in algorithm code?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, algorithms, comments

I will to align comments in another column, package algorithm.
(Similar question: [Faulty right alignment for comments in algorithmic package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/147016/faulty-right-alignment-for-comments-in-algorithmic-package)), but I will to become that result:

[image]

```
\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic}
\renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{\bgroup\hfill//~#1\egroup}

[...]

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{$function(n : \mathbb{N}_0) : \mathbb{N}_0$}
\label{algo1}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
   \REQUIRE $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$
   \STATE $result \leftarrow 0 : \mathbb{N}_0$
   \STATE $temp \leftarrow 1 : \mathbb{N}_0$
   \FOR[$n$ Durchläufe]{$i \leftarrow 0$ \TO $n-1$}
     \FOR{$j \leftarrow i$ \TO $i$}
       \STATE $temp \leftarrow temp \cdot 2$ \COMMENT{Multiplikation}
     \ENDFOR
     \STATE $result \leftarrow result + temp$ \COMMENT{Addition}
     \STATE $temp \leftarrow 1$
   \ENDFOR
   \RETURN $result$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

Comment: Please always supply a complete (`\documentclass` to `\end{document}`) example document that demonstrates the problem and allows people to test their answers.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is an [`algorithmicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) implementation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{algorithm,algcompatible,amssymb,amsmath}
\renewcommand{\COMMENT}[2][.5\linewidth]{%
  \leavevmode\hfill\makebox[#1][l]{//~#2}}
\algnewcommand\algorithmicto{\textbf{to}}
\algnewcommand\RETURN{\State \textbf{return} }
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{$\text{function}(n : \mathbb{N}_0) : \mathbb{N}_0$}\label{algo1}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \REQUIRE $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$
    \STATE $\text{result} \leftarrow 0 : \mathbb{N}_0$
    \STATE $\text{temp} \leftarrow 1 : \mathbb{N}_0$
    \FOR{$i \leftarrow 0$ \algorithmicto{} $n-1$} \COMMENT{$n$ Durchläufe}
      \FOR{$j \leftarrow i$ \algorithmicto{} $i$}
        \STATE $\text{temp} \leftarrow \text{temp} \cdot 2$ \COMMENT{Multiplikation}
      \ENDFOR
      \STATE $\text{result} \leftarrow \text{result} + \text{temp}$ \COMMENT{Addition}
      \STATE $\text{temp} \leftarrow 1$
    \ENDFOR
    \RETURN $\text{result}$
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

`\COMMENT[<len>]{<stuff>}` is reformatted to put the comment `<stuff>` in a box of width `<len>` (default is `.5\linewidth`) flush right. You can adjust this to your liking.

---

A pure [`algorithmic`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmic) implementation is somewhat different:

```
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\newlength{\commentindent}
\setlength{\commentindent}{.5\textwidth}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{\unskip\hfill\makebox[\commentindent][l]{//~#1}\par}
\LetLtxMacro{\oldalgorithmic}{\algorithmic}
\renewcommand{\algorithmic}[1][0]{%
  \oldalgorithmic[#1]%
  \renewcommand{\ALC@com}[1]{%
    \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{##1}{default}=0\else\algorithmiccomment{##1}\fi}%
}
\makeatother
```

It uses e-TeX (for the string comparison), but that can be changed. The reason for the difference in implementation is mainly because of the way loops are handled in `algorithmic` - the comment is inserted as an optional argument to the loop structure. As such, it's difficult to allow another optional argument for the length parameter as above in the `algorithmicx` implementation. The work-around is to define a length `\commentindent` that handles this in a similar way the optional argument would handle things.

Here's a full implementation, with the same output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic,amssymb,amsmath,letltxmacro}
\newlength{\commentindent}
\setlength{\commentindent}{.5\textwidth}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{\unskip\hfill\makebox[\commentindent][l]{//~#1}\par}
\LetLtxMacro{\oldalgorithmic}{\algorithmic}
\renewcommand{\algorithmic}[1][0]{%
  \oldalgorithmic[#1]%
  \renewcommand{\ALC@com}[1]{%
    \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{##1}{default}=0\else\algorithmiccomment{##1}\fi}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{$\text{function}(n : \mathbb{N}_0) : \mathbb{N}_0$}\label{algo1}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \REQUIRE $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$
    \STATE $\text{result} \leftarrow 0 : \mathbb{N}_0$
    \STATE $\text{temp} \leftarrow 1 : \mathbb{N}_0$
    \FOR[$n$ Durchläufe]{$i \leftarrow 0$ \TO $n-1$}
      \FOR{$j \leftarrow i$ \TO $i$}
        \STATE $\text{temp} \leftarrow \text{temp} \cdot 2$ \COMMENT{Multiplikation}
      \ENDFOR
      \STATE $\text{result} \leftarrow \text{result} + \text{temp}$ \COMMENT{Addition}
      \STATE $\text{temp} \leftarrow 1$
    \ENDFOR
    \RETURN $\text{result}$
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not sure if this is some change in `algorithmicx`, but I had to renew `\algorithmiccomment` instead of `\COMMENT`.

Comment: @paleonix: Then you're probably also using `\algorithmiccomment` in your code, not `\COMMENT`.

Comment: I'm using `\Comment`.

Comment: Both `\Comment` and customization through `\algorithmiccomment` are [documented (page 4)](https://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/algorithmicx.pdf). Like I said, this might have changed since 2014.