# Spacing issue with algorithmic and eqparbox

Tags: horizontal-alignment, algorithms, algorithmic

I am using the `algorithmic` package to display code. In order to get flush-right, left aligned comments, I also use the `eqparbox` package and redefine `\algorithmiccomment`; see minimal example below.

As can be seen in the attached snapshot, all the comments are left-aligned as intended except for the second one. I guess it should be possible to solve this by redefining or patching some command in `algorithmic.sty`, but after taking a look to that file, I could not identify the source of the problem. Any ideas?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{\hfill\eqparbox{COMMENT}{\{#1\}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}  
\STATE something \COMMENT{first comment}
\IF[second comment]{some condition} 
\STATE some other thing \COMMENT{3rd comm}
\STATE final thing \COMMENT{some final thoughts}
\ENDIF
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For some reason, the `\IF` line is shorter than the others.

Comment: There are ***many*** unprotected end-of-lines in the definition of the `algorithmic` environment. Basically all are unprotected except those which don't need to be. :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This issue is already known, see [Faulty right alignment for comments in algorithmic package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/147016/27635).

The right way is to use `algorithmicx` (specifically `algpseudocode` variant) instead of `algorithmic`. You can use its option `compatible` if you want to keep your code exactly as it is.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[compatible]{algpseudocode} % or \usepackage{algcompatible}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{\hfill\eqparbox{COMMENT}{\{#1\}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}
\STATE something \COMMENT{first comment}
\IF[second comment]{some condition}
\STATE some other thing \COMMENT{3rd comm}
\STATE final thing \COMMENT{some final thoughts}
\ENDIF
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is a fixed version of `algorithmic.sty`, save it as `fixed-algorithm.sty`

```
%%%%%%%%%%%% modified to protect end-of-lines
%%% see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229559/spacing-issue-with-algorithmic-and-eqparbox
%%
%% This is file `algorithmic.sty',
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% The original source files were:
%%
%% algorithms.dtx  (with options: `algorithmic')
%% This is a generated file.
%% 
%% Copyright (C) 1994-2004   Peter Williams <pwil3058@bigpond.net.au>
%% Copyright (C) 2005-2009   Rogério Brito <rbrito@ime.usp.br>
%% 
%% This document file is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
%% modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as
%% published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the
%% License, or (at your option) any later version.
%% 
%% This document file is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but
%% WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
%% MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU Lesser
%% General Public License for more details.
%% 
%% You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public License
%% along with this document file; if not, write to the Free Software
%% Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place - Suite 330, Boston, MA 02111-1307,
%% USA.
%% 
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1999/12/01]
\ProvidesPackage{fixed-algorithmic}
   [2009/08/24 v0.1 Document Style `algorithmic']
% The algorithmic.sty package:
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage{keyval}
\newboolean{ALC@noend}
\setboolean{ALC@noend}{false}
\newcounter{ALC@unique}    % new counter to make lines numbers be internally
\setcounter{ALC@unique}{0} % different in different algorithms
\newcounter{ALC@line}      % counter for current line
\newcounter{ALC@rem}       % counter for lines not printed
\newcounter{ALC@depth}
\newlength{\ALC@tlm}
%
\DeclareOption{noend}{\setboolean{ALC@noend}{true}}
%
\ProcessOptions
%
% For keyval-style options
\def\algsetup{\setkeys{ALG}}
%
% For indentation of algorithms
\newlength{\algorithmicindent}
\setlength{\algorithmicindent}{0pt}
\define@key{ALG}{indent}{\setlength{\algorithmicindent}{#1}}
\ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\algorithmicindent=0pt}}%
        {\setlength{\algorithmicindent}{1em}}{}
%
% For line numbers' delimiters
\newcommand{\ALC@linenodelimiter}{:}
\define@key{ALG}{linenodelimiter}{\renewcommand{\ALC@linenodelimiter}{#1}}
%
% For line numbers' size
\newcommand{\ALC@linenosize}{\footnotesize}
\define@key{ALG}{linenosize}{\renewcommand{\ALC@linenosize}{#1}}
%
% ALGORITHMIC
\newcommand{\algorithmicrequire}{\textbf{Require:}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicensure}{\textbf{Ensure:}}
\newcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{\{#1\}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicend}{\textbf{end}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicif}{\textbf{if}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicthen}{\textbf{then}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicelse}{\textbf{else}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicelsif}{\algorithmicelse\ \algorithmicif}
\newcommand{\algorithmicendif}{\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicif}
\newcommand{\algorithmicfor}{\textbf{for}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicforall}{\textbf{for all}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicdo}{\textbf{do}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicendfor}{\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicfor}
\newcommand{\algorithmicwhile}{\textbf{while}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicendwhile}{\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicwhile}
\newcommand{\algorithmicloop}{\textbf{loop}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicendloop}{\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicloop}
\newcommand{\algorithmicrepeat}{\textbf{repeat}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicuntil}{\textbf{until}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicprint}{\textbf{print}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicreturn}{\textbf{return}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicand}{\textbf{and}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicor}{\textbf{or}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicxor}{\textbf{xor}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicnot}{\textbf{not}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicto}{\textbf{to}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicinputs}{\textbf{inputs}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicoutputs}{\textbf{outputs}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicglobals}{\textbf{globals}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicbody}{\textbf{do}}
\newcommand{\algorithmictrue}{\textbf{true}}
\newcommand{\algorithmicfalse}{\textbf{false}}
\def\ALC@item[#1]{%
\if@noparitem \@donoparitem
  \else \if@inlabel \indent \par \fi
         \ifhmode \unskip\unskip \par \fi
         \if@newlist \if@nobreak \@nbitem \else
                        \addpenalty\@beginparpenalty
                        \addvspace\@topsep \addvspace{-\parskip}\fi
           \else \addpenalty\@itempenalty \addvspace\itemsep
          \fi
    \global\@inlabeltrue
\fi
\everypar{\global\@minipagefalse\global\@newlistfalse
          \if@inlabel\global\@inlabelfalse \hskip -\parindent \box\@labels
             \penalty\z@ \fi
          \everypar{}}\global\@nobreakfalse
\if@noitemarg \@noitemargfalse \if@nmbrlist \refstepcounter{\@listctr}\fi \fi
\sbox\@tempboxa{\makelabel{#1}}%
\global\setbox\@labels
 \hbox{\unhbox\@labels \hskip \itemindent
       \hskip -\labelwidth \hskip -\ALC@tlm
       \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\labelwidth
                \box\@tempboxa
          \else \hbox to\labelwidth {\unhbox\@tempboxa}\fi
       \hskip \ALC@tlm}\ignorespaces}
%
\newenvironment{algorithmic}[1][0]{%
\setcounter{ALC@depth}{\@listdepth}%
\let\@listdepth\c@ALC@depth
\let\@item\ALC@item
  \newcommand{\ALC@lno}{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\arabic{ALC@rem}}{0}}%
{{\ALC@linenosize \arabic{ALC@line}\ALC@linenodelimiter}}{}%
}%
\let\@listii\@listi
\let\@listiii\@listi
\let\@listiv\@listi
\let\@listv\@listi
\let\@listvi\@listi
\let\@listvii\@listi
  \newenvironment{ALC@g}{%
    \begin{list}{\ALC@lno}{ \itemsep\z@ \itemindent\z@
    \listparindent\z@ \rightmargin\z@
    \topsep\z@ \partopsep\z@ \parskip\z@\parsep\z@
    \leftmargin \algorithmicindent%1em
    \addtolength{\ALC@tlm}{\leftmargin}%
    }%
  }%
  {\end{list}}
  \newcommand{\ALC@it}{%
    \stepcounter{ALC@rem}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\arabic{ALC@rem}}{#1}}{\setcounter{ALC@rem}{0}}{}%
    \stepcounter{ALC@line}%
    \refstepcounter{ALC@unique}%
    \item\def\@currentlabel{\theALC@line}%
  }%
  \newcommand{\ALC@com}[1]{\ifthenelse{\equal{##1}{default}}%
{}{\ \algorithmiccomment{##1}}}%
  \newcommand{\REQUIRE}{\item[\algorithmicrequire]}%
  \newcommand{\ENSURE}{\item[\algorithmicensure]}%
  \newcommand{\PRINT}{\ALC@it\algorithmicprint{} \ }%
  \newcommand{\RETURN}{\ALC@it\algorithmicreturn{} \ }%
  \newcommand{\TRUE}{\algorithmictrue{}}%
  \newcommand{\FALSE}{\algorithmicfalse{}}%
  \newcommand{\AND}{\algorithmicand{} }%
  \newcommand{\OR}{\algorithmicor{} }%
  \newcommand{\XOR}{\algorithmicxor{} }%
  \newcommand{\NOT}{\algorithmicnot{} }%
  \newcommand{\TO}{\algorithmicto{} }%
  \newcommand{\STATE}{\ALC@it}%
  \newcommand{\STMT}{\ALC@it}%
  \newcommand{\COMMENT}[1]{\algorithmiccomment{##1}}%
  \newenvironment{ALC@inputs}{\begin{ALC@g}}{\end{ALC@g}}%
  \newenvironment{ALC@outputs}{\begin{ALC@g}}{\end{ALC@g}}%
  \newenvironment{ALC@globals}{\begin{ALC@g}}{\end{ALC@g}}%
  \newenvironment{ALC@body}{\begin{ALC@g}}{\end{ALC@g}}%
  \newenvironment{ALC@if}{\begin{ALC@g}}{\end{ALC@g}}%
  \newenvironment{ALC@for}{\begin{ALC@g}}{\end{ALC@g}}%
  \newenvironment{ALC@whl}{\begin{ALC@g}}{\end{ALC@g}}%
  \newenvironment{ALC@loop}{\begin{ALC@g}}{\end{ALC@g}}%
  \newenvironment{ALC@rpt}{\begin{ALC@g}}{\end{ALC@g}}%
  \renewcommand{\\}{\@centercr}%
  \newcommand{\INPUTS}[1][default]{\ALC@it\algorithmicinputs\ \ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@inputs}}%
  \newcommand{\ENDINPUTS}{\end{ALC@inputs}}%
  \newcommand{\OUTPUTS}[1][default]{\ALC@it\algorithmicoutputs\ \ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@outputs}}%
  \newcommand{\ENDOUTPUTS}{\end{ALC@outputs}}%
  \newcommand{\GLOBALS}{\ALC@it\algorithmicglobals\ }%
  \newcommand{\BODY}[1][default]{\ALC@it\algorithmicbody\ \ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@body}}%
  \newcommand{\ENDBODY}{\end{ALC@body}}%
  \newcommand{\IF}[2][default]{\ALC@it\algorithmicif\ ##2\ \algorithmicthen
\ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@if}}%
  \newcommand{\ELSE}[1][default]{\end{ALC@if}\ALC@it\algorithmicelse
\ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@if}}%
  \newcommand{\ELSIF}[2][default]%
{\end{ALC@if}\ALC@it\algorithmicelsif\ ##2\ \algorithmicthen
\ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@if}}%
  \newcommand{\FOR}[2][default]{\ALC@it\algorithmicfor\ ##2\ \algorithmicdo
\ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@for}}%
  \newcommand{\FORALL}[2][default]{\ALC@it\algorithmicforall\ ##2\ %
\algorithmicdo
\ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@for}}%
  \newcommand{\WHILE}[2][default]{\ALC@it\algorithmicwhile\ ##2\ %
\algorithmicdo
\ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@whl}}%
  \newcommand{\LOOP}[1][default]{\ALC@it\algorithmicloop
\ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@loop}}%
  \newcommand{\REPEAT}[1][default]{\ALC@it\algorithmicrepeat
\ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@rpt}}%
  \newcommand{\UNTIL}[1]{\end{ALC@rpt}\ALC@it\algorithmicuntil\ ##1}%
  \ifthenelse{\boolean{ALC@noend}}{%
    \newcommand{\ENDIF}{\end{ALC@if}}%
    \newcommand{\ENDFOR}{\end{ALC@for}}%
    \newcommand{\ENDWHILE}{\end{ALC@whl}}%
    \newcommand{\ENDLOOP}{\end{ALC@loop}}%
  }{%
    \newcommand{\ENDIF}{\end{ALC@if}\ALC@it\algorithmicendif}%
    \newcommand{\ENDFOR}{\end{ALC@for}\ALC@it\algorithmicendfor}%
    \newcommand{\ENDWHILE}{\end{ALC@whl}\ALC@it\algorithmicendwhile}%
    \newcommand{\ENDLOOP}{\end{ALC@loop}\ALC@it\algorithmicendloop}%
  }%
  \renewcommand{\@toodeep}{}%
  \begin{list}{\ALC@lno}{\setcounter{ALC@rem}{0}\setcounter{ALC@line}{0}%
    \itemsep\z@ \itemindent\z@ \listparindent\z@
    \partopsep\z@ \parskip\z@ \parsep\z@
    \labelsep 0.5em \topsep 0.2em
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{0}}%
  {\labelwidth 0.5em }%
  {\labelwidth  1.2em }%
\leftmargin\labelwidth \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
    \ALC@tlm\labelsep
  }%
}%
{\end{list}}
\endinput
%%
%% End of file `algorithmic.sty'.
```

Now you example (with `\usepackage{fixed-algorithmic}`) prints

[image]

Here's the `diff` of the two files (first is the fixed one):

```
123c123
< \newenvironment{algorithmic}[1][0]{%
---
> \newenvironment{algorithmic}[1][0]{
125,126c125,126
< \let\@listdepth\c@ALC@depth
< \let\@item\ALC@item
---
> \let\@listdepth\c@ALC@depth%
> \let\@item\ALC@item%
128c128
< \ifthenelse{\equal{\arabic{ALC@rem}}{0}}%
---
> \ifthenelse{\equal{\arabic{ALC@rem}}{0}}
130c130
< }%
---
> }
137c137
<   \newenvironment{ALC@g}{%
---
>   \newenvironment{ALC@g}{
142,144c142,144
<     \addtolength{\ALC@tlm}{\leftmargin}%
<     }%
<   }%
---
>     \addtolength{\ALC@tlm}{\leftmargin}
>     }
>   }
152c152
<   }%
---
>   }
154,189c154,189
< {}{\ \algorithmiccomment{##1}}}%
<   \newcommand{\REQUIRE}{\item[\algorithmicrequire]}%
<   \newcommand{\ENSURE}{\item[\algorithmicensure]}%
<   \newcommand{\PRINT}{\ALC@it\algorithmicprint{} \ }%
<   \newcommand{\RETURN}{\ALC@it\algorithmicreturn{} \ }%
<   \newcommand{\TRUE}{\algorithmictrue{}}%
<   \newcommand{\FALSE}{\algorithmicfalse{}}%
<   \newcommand{\AND}{\algorithmicand{} }%
<   \newcommand{\OR}{\algorithmicor{} }%
<   \newcommand{\XOR}{\algorithmicxor{} }%
<   \newcommand{\NOT}{\algorithmicnot{} }%
<   \newcommand{\TO}{\algorithmicto{} }%
<   \newcommand{\STATE}{\ALC@it}%
<   \newcommand{\STMT}{\ALC@it}%
<   \newcommand{\COMMENT}[1]{\algorithmiccomment{##1}}%
<   \newenvironment{ALC@inputs}{\begin{ALC@g}}{\end{ALC@g}}%
<   \newenvironment{ALC@outputs}{\begin{ALC@g}}{\end{ALC@g}}%
<   \newenvironment{ALC@globals}{\begin{ALC@g}}{\end{ALC@g}}%
<   \newenvironment{ALC@body}{\begin{ALC@g}}{\end{ALC@g}}%
<   \newenvironment{ALC@if}{\begin{ALC@g}}{\end{ALC@g}}%
<   \newenvironment{ALC@for}{\begin{ALC@g}}{\end{ALC@g}}%
<   \newenvironment{ALC@whl}{\begin{ALC@g}}{\end{ALC@g}}%
<   \newenvironment{ALC@loop}{\begin{ALC@g}}{\end{ALC@g}}%
<   \newenvironment{ALC@rpt}{\begin{ALC@g}}{\end{ALC@g}}%
<   \renewcommand{\\}{\@centercr}%
<   \newcommand{\INPUTS}[1][default]{\ALC@it\algorithmicinputs\ \ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@inputs}}%
<   \newcommand{\ENDINPUTS}{\end{ALC@inputs}}%
<   \newcommand{\OUTPUTS}[1][default]{\ALC@it\algorithmicoutputs\ \ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@outputs}}%
<   \newcommand{\ENDOUTPUTS}{\end{ALC@outputs}}%
<   \newcommand{\GLOBALS}{\ALC@it\algorithmicglobals\ }%
<   \newcommand{\BODY}[1][default]{\ALC@it\algorithmicbody\ \ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@body}}%
<   \newcommand{\ENDBODY}{\end{ALC@body}}%
<   \newcommand{\IF}[2][default]{\ALC@it\algorithmicif\ ##2\ \algorithmicthen
< \ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@if}}%
<   \newcommand{\ELSE}[1][default]{\end{ALC@if}\ALC@it\algorithmicelse
< \ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@if}}%
---
> {}{\ \algorithmiccomment{##1}}}
>   \newcommand{\REQUIRE}{\item[\algorithmicrequire]}
>   \newcommand{\ENSURE}{\item[\algorithmicensure]}
>   \newcommand{\PRINT}{\ALC@it\algorithmicprint{} \ }
>   \newcommand{\RETURN}{\ALC@it\algorithmicreturn{} \ }
>   \newcommand{\TRUE}{\algorithmictrue{}}
>   \newcommand{\FALSE}{\algorithmicfalse{}}
>   \newcommand{\AND}{\algorithmicand{} }
>   \newcommand{\OR}{\algorithmicor{} }
>   \newcommand{\XOR}{\algorithmicxor{} }
>   \newcommand{\NOT}{\algorithmicnot{} }
>   \newcommand{\TO}{\algorithmicto{} }
>   \newcommand{\STATE}{\ALC@it}
>   \newcommand{\STMT}{\ALC@it}
>   \newcommand{\COMMENT}[1]{\algorithmiccomment{##1}}
>   \newenvironment{ALC@inputs}{\begin{ALC@g}}{\end{ALC@g}}
>   \newenvironment{ALC@outputs}{\begin{ALC@g}}{\end{ALC@g}}
>   \newenvironment{ALC@globals}{\begin{ALC@g}}{\end{ALC@g}}
>   \newenvironment{ALC@body}{\begin{ALC@g}}{\end{ALC@g}}
>   \newenvironment{ALC@if}{\begin{ALC@g}}{\end{ALC@g}}
>   \newenvironment{ALC@for}{\begin{ALC@g}}{\end{ALC@g}}
>   \newenvironment{ALC@whl}{\begin{ALC@g}}{\end{ALC@g}}
>   \newenvironment{ALC@loop}{\begin{ALC@g}}{\end{ALC@g}}
>   \newenvironment{ALC@rpt}{\begin{ALC@g}}{\end{ALC@g}}
>   \renewcommand{\\}{\@centercr}
>   \newcommand{\INPUTS}[1][default]{\ALC@it\algorithmicinputs\ \ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@inputs}}
>   \newcommand{\ENDINPUTS}{\end{ALC@inputs}}
>   \newcommand{\OUTPUTS}[1][default]{\ALC@it\algorithmicoutputs\ \ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@outputs}}
>   \newcommand{\ENDOUTPUTS}{\end{ALC@outputs}}
>   \newcommand{\GLOBALS}{\ALC@it\algorithmicglobals\ }
>   \newcommand{\BODY}[1][default]{\ALC@it\algorithmicbody\ \ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@body}}
>   \newcommand{\ENDBODY}{\end{ALC@body}}
>   \newcommand{\IF}[2][default]{\ALC@it\algorithmicif\ ##2\ \algorithmicthen%
> \ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@if}}
>   \newcommand{\ELSE}[1][default]{\end{ALC@if}\ALC@it\algorithmicelse%
> \ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@if}}
191,194c191,194
< {\end{ALC@if}\ALC@it\algorithmicelsif\ ##2\ \algorithmicthen
< \ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@if}}%
<   \newcommand{\FOR}[2][default]{\ALC@it\algorithmicfor\ ##2\ \algorithmicdo
< \ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@for}}%
---
> {\end{ALC@if}\ALC@it\algorithmicelsif\ ##2\ \algorithmicthen%
> \ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@if}}
>   \newcommand{\FOR}[2][default]{\ALC@it\algorithmicfor\ ##2\ \algorithmicdo%
> \ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@for}}
196,197c196,197
< \algorithmicdo
< \ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@for}}%
---
> \algorithmicdo%
> \ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@for}}
199,217c199,217
< \algorithmicdo
< \ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@whl}}%
<   \newcommand{\LOOP}[1][default]{\ALC@it\algorithmicloop
< \ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@loop}}%
<   \newcommand{\REPEAT}[1][default]{\ALC@it\algorithmicrepeat
< \ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@rpt}}%
<   \newcommand{\UNTIL}[1]{\end{ALC@rpt}\ALC@it\algorithmicuntil\ ##1}%
<   \ifthenelse{\boolean{ALC@noend}}{%
<     \newcommand{\ENDIF}{\end{ALC@if}}%
<     \newcommand{\ENDFOR}{\end{ALC@for}}%
<     \newcommand{\ENDWHILE}{\end{ALC@whl}}%
<     \newcommand{\ENDLOOP}{\end{ALC@loop}}%
<   }{%
<     \newcommand{\ENDIF}{\end{ALC@if}\ALC@it\algorithmicendif}%
<     \newcommand{\ENDFOR}{\end{ALC@for}\ALC@it\algorithmicendfor}%
<     \newcommand{\ENDWHILE}{\end{ALC@whl}\ALC@it\algorithmicendwhile}%
<     \newcommand{\ENDLOOP}{\end{ALC@loop}\ALC@it\algorithmicendloop}%
<   }%
<   \renewcommand{\@toodeep}{}%
---
> \algorithmicdo%
> \ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@whl}}
>   \newcommand{\LOOP}[1][default]{\ALC@it\algorithmicloop%
> \ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@loop}}
>   \newcommand{\REPEAT}[1][default]{\ALC@it\algorithmicrepeat%
> \ALC@com{##1}\begin{ALC@rpt}}
>   \newcommand{\UNTIL}[1]{\end{ALC@rpt}\ALC@it\algorithmicuntil\ ##1}
>   \ifthenelse{\boolean{ALC@noend}}{
>     \newcommand{\ENDIF}{\end{ALC@if}}
>     \newcommand{\ENDFOR}{\end{ALC@for}}
>     \newcommand{\ENDWHILE}{\end{ALC@whl}}
>     \newcommand{\ENDLOOP}{\end{ALC@loop}}
>   }{
>     \newcommand{\ENDIF}{\end{ALC@if}\ALC@it\algorithmicendif}
>     \newcommand{\ENDFOR}{\end{ALC@for}\ALC@it\algorithmicendfor}
>     \newcommand{\ENDWHILE}{\end{ALC@whl}\ALC@it\algorithmicendwhile}
>     \newcommand{\ENDLOOP}{\end{ALC@loop}\ALC@it\algorithmicendloop}
>   }
>   \renewcommand{\@toodeep}{}
219,225c219,225
<     \itemsep\z@ \itemindent\z@ \listparindent\z@
<     \partopsep\z@ \parskip\z@ \parsep\z@
<     \labelsep 0.5em \topsep 0.2em
< \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{0}}%
<   {\labelwidth 0.5em }%
<   {\labelwidth  1.2em }%
< \leftmargin\labelwidth \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
---
>     \itemsep\z@ \itemindent\z@ \listparindent\z@%
>     \partopsep\z@ \parskip\z@ \parsep\z@%
>     \labelsep 0.5em \topsep 0.2em%
> \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{0}}
>   {\labelwidth 0.5em }
>   {\labelwidth  1.2em }
> \leftmargin\labelwidth \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}
227,228c227,228
<   }%
< }%
---
>   }
> }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possible solution using the [`tikzpagenodes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzpagenodes) package and the [`tikzmark`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark) library to place the comments flushed to the right margin:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\newcounter{mycomm}

\renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{mycomm}%
  \tikzmark{start-\themycomm}%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,anchor=east] 
    at (current page text area.east|-{pic cs:start-\themycomm}) 
    {\eqparbox{COMMENT}{\{#1\}}};
}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithmic}  
\STATE something \COMMENT{first comment}
\IF[second comment]{some condition} 
\STATE some other thing \COMMENT{third comment}
\IF[fourth comment]{some condition} 
\STATE final thing \COMMENT{some final thoughts}
\ENDIF
\ENDIF
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

[image]